# How can I not repeat the same case after I use it

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

So, I made a burger class with  a method for extra stuff, my question is how can I use case 0,1,2 only 1 time, like if I use case 0, I can't use it anymore, I can use only 1 and 2, If I use case 1 after 0 , then I can use only case 2 since I used case 0 and 1 before , It's possible to do something like that ? If yes how ?
The code:

````
         boolean flag=true;
         while(flag){
             System.out.println("Enter your choice for extra toppings ");
             int choice=scanner.nextInt();
             scanner.nextLine();
             switch(choice) {
                 case 0:
                     double salad = 0.35;
                     setAdditional(getAdditional() + salad);
                     System.out.println("salad added\n");
                     break;
                 case 1:
                     double bacon=1.05;
                     setAdditional(getAdditional()+bacon);
                     System.out.println("Bacon added \n");
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     double fries=0.79;
                     setAdditional(getAdditional()+fries);
                     System.out.println("fries added \n");
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     System.out.println("Done");
                     flag=false;

        }

        }
    } ```
````

Comment: set some boolean like `saladUsed` and check whether it's true as soon as you enter the `case`. If it's true do nothing or throw an error.

Comment: It entirely depends on your logic. For example, you can keep a HashMap<String, Boolean> which will have salad, bacon, fries as keys and true as value. If used, make the boolean false. If the user takes the same item again, the boolean will be false, you can throw some error now

Comment: Great Idea, I will try that too, thanks.

Comment: comment changed to answer below.

Comment: @TomElias There is no point in arguing "array is faster than map" for educational code that relies on USER INPUT anyway. Performance is irrelevant here. And note that implicit mapping of integer indexes to "meaning" ... is quite harder to understand than a map that says "beacon" key costs "1.05" float value.

Comment: you are correct, it is also more memory efficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  boolean flag = true;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    while (flag) {
        System.out.println("Enter your choice for extra toppings ");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
            switch (choice) {
                case 0:
                    if (!set.contains(choice)) {
                        double salad = 0.35;
                        setAdditional(getAdditional() + salad);
                        System.out.println("salad added\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Added already");
                    }
                    continue;
                case 1:
                    double bacon = 1.05;
                    setAdditional(getAdditional() + bacon);
                    System.out.println("Bacon added \n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    double fries = 0.79;
                    setAdditional(getAdditional() + fries);
                    System.out.println("fries added \n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Done");
                    flag = false;

            }
            set.add(choice);
        }

    }
```

so I did it with Set in the end, only for salad, but it's the same for the rest, if someone else needs it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

your cases go by integer numbers, so an array of boolean with 1 element for every option.

`boolean[] allowed = new boolean[options];` (faster than hasMap of string to boolean).

add a check just before the "switch" statement:

```
if(allowed[choice] && choice != 3) {...}
```

you should also create an integer constant STOP_OPTION or something like that and use it in the above if-statement and in the final "case" of your switch statement. in your example, set it to 3. then later you can change it without replacing all instances of "3" in your code. but that's more of a styling suggestion.

the "flag" boolean is also redundant, the while loop can just check if choice != 3. be careful of NumberFormatExceptions!

good luck!